# Get Json search result of ALL count pages from json loadMore

Tags: java, android, json

I need to get results in `SearhView` from all json files fetched in url

My code for get Json result:

```
int count = 0;
    String url = "https://myweb.com.br/view/"+count+".json";

getData(count)
```

Getting data:

```
private void getData(int count) {
        // creating a new variable for our request queue
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        // in this case the data we are getting is in the form
        // of array so we are making a json array request.
        // below is the line where we are making an json array
        // request and then extracting data from each json object.
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://vixentpost.000webhostapp.com/vix-ent/"+count+".json", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    courseRV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        // creating a new json object and
                        // getting each object from our json array.
                        try {
                            // we are getting each json object.
                            JSONObject responseObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            // now we get our response from API in json object format.
                            // in below line we are extracting a string with
                            // its key value from our json object.
                            // similarly we are extracting all the strings from our json object.
                            String courseName = responseObj.getString("courseName");
                            String courseTracks = responseObj.getString("courseTracks");
                            String courseMode = responseObj.getString("courseMode");
                            String courseImageURL = responseObj.getString("courseimg");
                            courseArrayList.add(new CourseModal(courseName, courseMode, courseTracks, courseImageURL));

                            // on below line we are adding our array list to our adapter class.
                            courseRVAdapter = new CourseRVAdapter(MainActivity.this, courseArrayList);

                            // on below line we are setting
                            // adapter to our recycler view.
                            courseRV.setAdapter(courseRVAdapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to get the data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        queue.getCache().clear();

    }
```

For `loadMore` data in another count Json:

```
nestedSV.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                    // on scroll change we are checking when users scroll as bottom.
                    if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                        // in this method we are incrementing page number,
                        // making progress bar visible and calling get data method.
                        count++;
                        String page = String.valueOf(count);
                        // on below line we are making our progress bar visible.
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, page, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        
                        getData(count);
                        courseRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
```

My search Json:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String newText) {
                    courseRVAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    courseRVAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        return true;
    }
```

My `SearchFilter` in `Adapter`:

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    courseModalArrayList = modelArray;
                } else {

                    ArrayList<CourseModal> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (CourseModal carModel : modelArray) {

                        if (carModel.getCourseName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toString().toLowerCase()) |
                            (carModel.getcourseModes().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toString().toLowerCase()))) {

                            filteredList.add(carModel);
                        }
                    }

                    courseModalArrayList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = courseModalArrayList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                courseModalArrayList = (ArrayList<CourseModal>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

That is, each `loadMore` loads a Json file, however in the search I need to get results from all files. But the result appears only for the current json file and not all (count) pages of the json. How is this possible?

I've tried firing all page numbers but it doesn't return just one result